# Reproduce Android Monkey Script

Tags: android, monkey

I ran the Monkey tool (the tool to perform stress testing on Android application) and I got some script file that have this form:

```
type= raw events
count= -1
speed= 1.0
start data >>
LaunchActivity(com.amaze.filemanager,com.amaze.filemanager.activities.MainActivity)
DispatchPointer(6934862,6934862,0,517.0,124.0,0.0,0.0,0,1.0,1.0,0,0)
DispatchPointer(6934862,6934867,1,520.041,127.07279,0.0,0.0,0,1.0,1.0,0,0)
GUIGen(3)
DispatchTrackball(-1,6945789,2,1.0,-3.0,0.0,0.0,0,1.0,1.0,0,0)
...
```

I would like to re-execute such sequence of events again, using the produced script.
How can I do that?

Comment: Just curious here, how where you able to get this script from the Monkey tool ?

Comment: Do you want to loop your script file for a certain no of time?

Comment: @FlyingPumba I just run monkey from the command line, with a desired verbosity level and number of input, redirecting the output on a text file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need `adb` for the same. First you will create the file on your local

**monkey.script**

```
type= raw events
count= -1
speed= 1.0
start data >>
LaunchActivity(com.amaze.filemanager,com.amaze.filemanager.activities.MainActivity)
DispatchPointer(6934862,6934862,0,517.0,124.0,0.0,0.0,0,1.0,1.0,0,0)
DispatchPointer(6934862,6934867,1,520.041,127.07279,0.0,0.0,0,1.0,1.0,0,0)
GUIGen(3)
DispatchTrackball(-1,6945789,2,1.0,-3.0,0.0,0.0,0,1.0,1.0,0,0)
```

Then you will copy it to your phone

```
adb push ./monkey.script /sdcard/Download
```

And then you can run the script from adb

```
$ adb shell monkey -f /sdcard/Download/monkey.script 1
Events injected: 4
## Network stats: elapsed time=10ms (0ms mobile, 0ms wifi, 10ms not connected)
```

Comment: Any explanation on the downvote? Please comment while downvoting. This has been tested before posting

Comment: thankyou for suggesting the script. Can you please give me some link or material to study further. I am also working on automation and need help

Comment: You can start here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vt8EUQtqBuA

Comment: I checked the video, Actaully I need documentation for the command which I can use in my script

Comment: I checked the video, Actually I need documentation for the command which I can use in my script, like what does "GUIGen" command means and what is the meaning of count = -1 in your code.