# Save Android Monkey random run to script format for later replay

Tags: android, android-testing, android-monkey

Is there a way to save the random run of [Android Monkey](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html) into a script with the proper format to later replay it by running:

```
adb shell monkey -p <package_name> -f script_file 1
```

**EDIT:**

I know there is a seed flag (`-s`), but that's not what I want. I have to be able to work with the generated script before feeding it back to the Monkey.

Comment: Note that the `-f` switch is undocumented.

Comment: Yes, it seems a bit obscure. I'm looking at another question that seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669486/reproduce-android-monkey-script/49930319#49930319
Somehow op there was able to make it, so there might be a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an easy way, but you could do a reverse engineering on the [monkey script source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development.git/+/master/cmds/monkey/src/com/android/commands/monkey/MonkeySourceScript.java#307) to create a script that takes the output of the monkey command and generates the monkey script.

So you could run:

`adb shell monkey -p <package_name> -v -v 1 > monkey-logs.txt`

And then*:

`convert-to-monkey-script.sh monkey-logs.txt`

For example, one output of the monkey call:

```
Replaying 11 events with speed 1.0
:Sending Touch (ACTION_DOWN): 0:(450.0,450.0)
:Sending Touch (ACTION_UP): 0:(450.0,450.0)
Sleeping for 45 milliseconds
...
```

Becomes the following monkey script (read the [monkey source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development.git/+/master/cmds/monkey/src/com/android/commands/monkey/MonkeySourceScript.java#307) to understand better the arguments):

```
type= raw events
count= 2
speed= 1.0
start data >>
DispatchPointer(6934862,6934862,0,450.0,450.0,0.0,0.0,0,1.0,1.0,0,0)
DispatchPointer(6934862,6934862,1,450.0,450.0,0.0,0.0,0,1.0,1.0,0,0)
```

Which can be run with (with the content above in the monkey.script file and after a adb push):

`adb shell monkey -p <package_name> -f monkey.script 1`

I've made a simple gist **for myself** that convert **adb taps** commands into monkey script format (because they're faster) [here](https://gist.github.com/Grohden/9b75907b9a30377d7f518059b9b3b6d2), so I think that is possible to make a general script for that.

*Note: `convert-to-monkey-script.sh` doesn't exist. As I said, someone COULD do it

Answer (score 1):

There is no option for saving script, but you can use **seed** that acts like a seed in random number generator so same seed leads to same events. Here is an example:

```
adb shell monkey -p com.package -s 123 500
```

This will run Monkey on package 'com.package' with seed value of '123' and produce 500 events.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I'm looking for. I edited the question to give more context.

Comment: I haven't. I am gonna take a look and try to figure out how to use it.